# How to load a table from a file and allow for edit and save (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am faily new to C#/.NET and I am developing a WPF application using the MVVM parardigm. THe main window has several tabs and in one of the tabitems I am looking to embed a table that can be loaded that is populated by reading an XML file. The XML file contains data about instruments. After reading about it, it looks like **DataGrid** is the construct I want. Below is the code of the dataGrid that I inserted into that particular tab in my **MainWindow.xaml** file:

```
<TabItem Header="Device Info" Width="100" Height="25">
            <DataGrid Name="DeviceInfoGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alias" Binding="{Binding Alias}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Interface Type" Binding="{Binding InterfaceType}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resource ID" Binding="{Binding VisaResource}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MFG" Binding="{Binding Make}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cal Date" Binding="{Binding CalDate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cal Due Date" Binding="{Binding CalDueDate}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                
            </DataGrid>

        </TabItem>
```

Now, I believe that in my **MainWindow.xaml.cs** (the View-Model?), that is where I want to define what the data context of that Data Grid is? The Microsoft examples suggest that I should bind my DataGrid to a DataTable, which gets populated by some function that can read from an XML file.

Basically, I want this tab, when its opened, to read an XML file and populate rows of the Data Grid based on the info in the XML. If there is an element for "Alias" in the file, then read that element and store it in the next available row under the "alias" column. Then I want to allow the user to edit the content displayed in the DataGrid and automatically save any changes to the XML file after exiting that tab.

There are a lot of concepts going on here with regards to MVVM and the various classes offered in .NET (grids, tables etc..) that I'm struggling to connect in my head and see how it would all come together. I would appreciate any pointers. You don't have to get into the nitty gritty of implementation, but if you could outline the main building blocks of what I would need and let me know if I'm on the right path that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting off, you are mistaken with a lot of fundamental MVVM concepts. There are plenty of good resources out there for you to learn. You can use the following as a basis for your future research into WPF and MVVM:

1.

> I believe that in my MainWindow.xaml.cs (the View-Model?)

This is your code-behind, not your VM. Anything ending in ".xaml.cs" is the code behind for the associated xaml file. The combination of the .xaml.cs and the .xaml file forms the V (View) in MVVM.

2.

> that is where I want to define what the data context of that Data Grid is

We are getting closer to the VM. There are a couple ways of defining the data context, but is commonly defined in your XAML as that allows easy binding to a View Model parameter in your View Model. This is shown in the below example

3.

> read an XML file and populate rows of the Data Grid based on the info in the XML

I personally approach this with View Model Factories and Data Providers. This is a reasonably broad topic with many acceptable solutions, so for the purposes of this response, I am going to neglect answering this because it is a bit outside the scope of these fundamental MVVM concepts. Instead, we can call this the M (model) layer of your MVVM. I am omitting how we read and write the data however.

4.

> MVVM and the various classes offered in .NET (grids, tables etc..)

Forget about all this for now and just focus on basics.

**Getting into bare bones MVVM for you**

*Note: the MVVM community toolkit simplifies a lot of this. This is not using the toolkit as it is beneficial to understand the absolute basics first*

You are going to define 3 view models. Remember, your view models need INotifyPropertyChanged

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataGridViewModel dataGridVM;

    public DataGridViewModel DataGridVM 
    { 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        get => dataGridVM;
        set
        {
            dataGridVM = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProperyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DataGridVM)));
        }
    }
}

public class DataGridViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel> DataGridRows { get; set; }
}

public class DataGridRowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private string alias;
    public string Alias
    {
        get => alias;
        set 
        { 
            alias = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProperyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Alias))); 
        }
    }
    
    //Continue with the rest of your parameters...
    
}
```

And then in your .xaml views:

MainView:

```xml
<Window>
    <!--I am ommitting all the namespace declarations and such-->
    <namespace:MyGridView DataContext = "{Binding DataGridVM}"/>
</Window>
```

MyGridView:

```xml
<MyGridView>
    <!--I am ommitting all the namespace declarations-->
    <DataGrid ItemsSource = "{Binding DataGridRows}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alias" Binding="{Binding Alias}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <!--Then continue with the rest of your columns, bound to the parameters-->
    </DataGrid>

</MyGridView>
```

The one thing I have omitted from explaining:

- Your MainWindow's data context needs to be defined in your App.xaml.cs along with the creation of your view models (in lieu of other object initialization architecture patterns). This will quickly branch into other app architecture styles. I will let you explore those

Good luck

Comment: Also consider making a ViewModelBase that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. On your own, you can learn how to extend that class and properly raise the propertychanged event

Comment: Thanks @jgrmn. I also posted the following question which is related to this one if you'd like to take a look. Trying to understand MVVM took me down the rabbit hole of first needing to understand events and delegates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889237/understanding-events-and-delegates-in-the-context-of-mvvm-and-wpf-apps