# Understanding events and delegates in the context of MVVM and WPF apps

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a code base that I inherited from someone for a WFP app. The app builds and works, but I'm trying to understand the underlying mechanism of the events and delegates at work. Bear with me here because I am fairly new to C#/.NET.

To simplify things, I will focus on one field that is present in the main window of the app. This is for the 'operator ID' field (string to enter operator name). Here is the code for that element in my XAML file.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding OperatorID}" Grid.Column="1" 
                         TextChanged="OperatorIDBox_TextChanged"
                         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18"
                         Width="200" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Now, in my "code-behind" xaml.cs file, I have the following (event handler?) method:

```
 private void OperatorIDBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as MyModel).OperatorID = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    }
```

Finally, in the "model" we have this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

and this

```
private string operatorID;
        public string OperatorID
        {
            get { return operatorID; }
            set
            {
                operatorID = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

I can't decide which way to think about this. One way is that when the text value is changed in the operatorID text box, the **TextChanged** property is flagged. That property in turn points to the function **OperatorIDBox_TextChanged** , which then goes and updates the actual property in the model with this code

```
            (DataContext as MyModel).OperatorID = (sender as TextBox).Text;
```

In the model the setter for the OperatorID property looks like this:

```
         set
            {
                operatorID = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

Which I believe 'raises' the event after setting the property. But didn't we already 'raise' the event when "TextChanged" was fired in the XAML element and we executed the **OperatorIDBox_TextChanged** method and thus update the property in the model? In my head its a circular logic and I can't understand the actual sequence of events. Furthermore, what is the data-binding doing here? In the XAML when we say **Text="{Binding OperatorID}** I initially thought that this would take care of all the event handling under the hood.

Also, what is meant by **(DataContext as MyModel)** and **(sender as TextBox)**?? Why not just say MyModel.OperatorID = sender.TextBox?

In summary, it's not clear to me in the above architecture what the sequence of events are when someone changes the value of the OperatorID text box. Which peiece of the code is the event, delegate, event handler etc.. and how do they all fit together? And how does Data Context and binding fit into this? That is not clear to me at all. In previous programming environments (CVI for test automation using C-code), a lot of this was abstracted away and we simply had a "callback" function that you define which would fire if you did a certain event like clicked a button. I can conceptualize that in my head easily because its simpler e.g.

1. Click the start button
2. The CLICK_BUTTON event mask is passed to your callback function
3. callback function has some logic to handle CLICK_BUTTON event.

But this whole event/delegate stuff in C# has got me confused.

I would appreciate any insights! Thank you!

Comment: you have merged **many** questions in one.  You are right, OperatorIDBox_TextChanged is the `event handler`, which gets invoked by the system since you have mentioned it in XAML for "TextChanged" event. The setter in your model is raising event for any other modules[that may be listening for propertyChanged event]. The `sender as TextBox` is for `typecast`, since the type of sender is object, you need to typecast and then access its property named `Text`. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: This code is somewhat unusual, you will get the same behaviour without any code-behind (which is generally preferred) by using `{Binding OperatorID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`.

Comment: also `Delay` option of binding is usefull (when you are using `PropertyChanged`)  especially for filtering ... and to addition to Klaus comment default value for `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus` so for now `OperatorID` is only updated when your TextBox is loosing focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JonasH's answer is totally correct, but I would like to offer an alternate interpretation.

**DLDR:**
Remove your `OperatorIDBox_TextChanged` method in the code behind and handle all changes through binding on your View Model

MVVM abstracts the View layer away from any other layer such that the View knows very little about any other layer of your application. This allows Views to be much more maintainable and duplicatable as they are no dependencies between your View and any other layer of your application. I say that the View knows "very little" rather than "nothing" about other layers because at an absolute minimum, the View will need to know that there is a property named `OperatorID` somewhere on the View Model. The View you shared with the XAML and associated code behind violates MVVM principles because the View has a direct dependency on the View Model. The dependency is right here:

```cs
(DataContext as MyModel).OperatorID = (sender as TextBox).Text;
```

In this scenario, your code behind knows (has reference to) the View Model.

Following MVVM principles, we therefore need to remove this line of code to get rid of the dependency. The question is therefore: how will we update the View if we are removing the `TextChanged` event?

This is done through data binding and by raising the `PropertyChanged` event on your View Model, which you are already doing.

Before we quickly review that, I want to correct your terminology as it is important when first considering MVVM. You mention the following:

> Finally, in the "model" we have this:
>
> `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

Based on this implementation, this is in fact your View Model, not your Model. The model is the layer of your application that deals with all your business logic, data storage, and data IO (api's, db's, etc...). The View Model is what glues together your View and your Model by exposing properties that your View can bind to. You can think of it as "a model for your view".

Getting into the property on your View Model, following the above logic, whenever the value of the dependency property you are bound to on the view changes, it will update the property on your view model. You can control the data flow of the binding by setting the Binding Mode. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0) documentation. By default, the data flow is two way, but you can be verbose and specify that yourself in your view, if you would like - doesn't really change anything. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.mode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-data-binding-mode) for details on the default binding data flow. From the opposite side, if you want to update the value in the View, you can assign a new value to the bound property in your View Model, so long as the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invokes the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter.

From that, you might ask: if my property invokes `PropertyChanged` in its setter, won't that create a never ending loop of setting the new property?

No, it will not. When the `PropertyChanged` event is raised, WPF will check if the new property is different than the value of the dependency property. If it is different, the dependency property's value will update, if it is the same, the process will end.

For buttons, you bind the command to an `ICommand` property on your View Model. This is a bit outside the scope of this question though, but follows similar principles.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when using MVVM you should prefer to use bindings. I.e. replace the TextChanged with

```
Text="{Binding OperatorID}"
```

Bindings are usually two way per default for things that take user input. You can specify the mode explicitly, `Mode=TwoWay`. In my experience this is rarely needed, but can be confusing when it is. So if the property is set in the view model, the `PropertyChanged` event will be raised, and the wpf magic will update the corresponding text field. If the user changes the text the OperatorID setter will be called, and wpf will be smart enough to not cause infinite recursion.

If a binding does not work I use the following checklist

1. check the Output Window in Visual Studio for data binding error messages
2. Ensure all models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or some other INotify interface)
3. Ensure that everything you want to bind to are properties
4. Check that there is an actual dataContext. Use the [xaml inspection tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022) to verify.
5. Ensure that you raise PropertyChanged whenever a property is changed from your code. Sometimes helper methods are used for this, for example:

```
private string myProperty;
public string MyProperty{
   get => myProperty;
   set => Set(ref myProperty, value);
}
private void Set<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
    {
        field = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

To handle buttons I prefer to use a custom `DelegateCommand`-class. This implements the `ICommand` interface, so it can be bound to the `Command`-property of a button. This object simply calls a `Action` delegate in the execute method. This give you a callback similar to other frameworks, while still avoiding code behind for buttons.

If you are using the MVVM pattern it is probably a good idea to try to avoid code behind, but in some cases there are few good alternatives. If that is the case something adding event handlers and code behind might be the best approach, but I that is probably not the case for a simple text box.

> Also, what is meant by (DataContext as MyModel) and (sender as TextBox)?? Why not just say MyModel.OperatorID = sender.TextBox?

I would assume `MyModel` is the typename of your model, if so it cannot be used directly. You can keep an explicit reference to your model in your code behind, something like:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private MyViewModel model;
    public MyWindow (MyViewModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        InitializeComponent();
```

This way you can just use `model` instead of `(DataContext as MyModel)`. But in many cases you will not create your view explicitly, and then this method does not apply. To get rid of the sender you need to add a name to your textbox in the xaml code, i.e. `x:Name="myTextBox"`, so you can use `myTextBox.Text` instead of `(sender as TextBox).Text`.

Comment: "*If a binding does not work*" - first of all check the Output Window in Visual Studio for data binding error messages. "*Bindings are usually two way per default*" - only when the target property has the BindsTwoWayByDefault property metadata flag, which is typically set for all those properties that are actively set by the control, like TextBox.Text. Bindings per se are OneWay by default.

Comment: Great, this is even more confusing. So for those properties that bind two-way by default, I suppose I can just use data-binding. Otherwise, I will need to define an event handler function like the one shown in my code-behind.

Comment: @ReelThymeOS For those properties where you need a two-way binding, but which do not bind two-way by default, just set `Mode=TwoWay` on the Binding. You do not need any event handlers at all.

Comment: @Clemens Fair points, I added some clarifications.